# Defining the levels of dataframe columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

I am trying to redefine the levels that are assigned when I am using cbind to create a dataframe from select columns of other dataframes.  The dataframes contain integers, and the rownames are strings:

```
outTable<-data.frame(cbind(contRes$wt, bRes$log2FoldChange, cRes$log2FoldChange, dRes$log2FoldChange, aRes$log2FoldChange), row.names=row.names(aRes))
```

Using the following, I get the levels of the columns:

```
levels(as.factor(colnames(outTable)))
[1] "F" "N" "RH" "RK" "W"
```

I would like to change that order by passing something like:

```
levels(as.factor(colnames(outTable)))<-c("W", "RK", "RH", "F", "N")
```

but I get the error:

```
could not find function "as.factor<-"
```

The end purpose is to set the X axis order of a boxplot in ggplot2.  Am I approaching this the right way?  if so, what am I missing, and if not how would be the best way to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
factor(colnames(outTable), levels=c("W", "RK", "RH", "F", "N"))
```

If you use `levels()<-` you will simply rename/replace level names; you don't re-order them. This is certainly not he behavior you want. The best way to re-order them all is to just use `factor()`

Comment: Hi,  I tried this, and no errors were thrown, but when I re-run the levels(as.factor(colnames(outTable)))   command, I still get the prior order, and the plotting is still ordered the same way.  Am I missing some step?

Comment: Why are you re-running that? You would need to save the results of this command to a variable. Then just use that variable for plotting. No need for as.factor.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify levels as an argument in the as.factor function

```
factor(colnames(outTable), levels = c("W", "RK", "RH", "F", "N"), ordered=T)
```

Comment: Hi, this throws the "Error in as.factor(colnames(outTable), levels = c("W", "RK", "RH", "F", "N")  : 
  unused argument (levels = c("W", "RK", "RH", "F", "N")).  Am I missing something?

Comment: My mistake, you should use the factor() function, not the as.factor() function. Also use the argument ordered = T to retain the order